# Polymorphic type declaration in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

when I write a type that e.g. only accepts strings: `let type t1 = string`
I can do `let name : t1 = "A"`, but not `let age : t1 = 1`

But when I want to have a generic type that accepts any data type I have to do this: `let type 'a t2 = 'a` So I can do both `let name : t2 = "A"`, `let age : t2 = 1`.

But why do I have to write `let type` **'a** `t2 = 'a` instead of `let type t2 = 'a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form

```ml
let type t1 = string
```

is not syntactically valid OCaml.
I imagine that you meant:

```ml
type t1 = string
```

Similarly, with the type constructor `t2` defined as

```ml
type 'a t2 = 'a
```

then

```ml
let x : t2 = "hi"
```

is a type error because `t2` is not a type but a type constructor of arity one.
The closest valid definition would be:

```ml
let x: string t2 = "hi"
```

which is equivalent

```ml
let x: 'a t2 = "hi"
```

because the type variable `'a` is equated to `'a = string` when inferring the type of `x`. But `'a t2` is an abbreviation for `'a`, thus the above is still the same as

```ml
let x : string = "hi"
```

At a higher level, there is no useful generic type that accepts any data¹. Indeed, if it existed such type would break the type system.

¹ There are an advanced feature (GADTs or record with polymorphic fields) that allows to either create black-hole types that can carry a data of any kind but forbids any use of the data or types without any values of this type. However, it is probably better to first familiarize yourself with the core part of the type system  before exploring those area.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @octachron's answer, you can think of a declaration like `type 'a t = 'a` as the declaration of a function over types: given a type `'a`, `t` will produce a new type `'a t` (which in this case is just `'a`). So you need the `'a` just like you would need to declare the parameters in a function.

This shouldn't be confused with the occurrences of `'a` in an explicit typing form like `expr : 'a t`. In this case, OCaml thinks of `'a` as a type variable, which may or may not denote polymorphism. If you actually wanted to have polymorphism as is the polymorphic type, you'd have to introduce a polymorphic type variable either with `'a. ...` or with a `type a`:

```ml
let id : 'a. 'a -> 'a = fun x -> x

let id (type a) (x : a) : a = x
```

However, note that these forms are not quite equivalent, there are subtle differences, and they are in any case different (in general, not in this specific example) from `let id : 'a -> 'a = fun x -> x` or `let id (x : 'a) : 'a = x`.